# Plugable dynamic pages on azure

Tags: dynamic, azure

I have a scenario, we have a template based website and templates are aspx web pages, our designers regularly create these templates, how can we store these templates on azure such that we just have to upload templates and not have to upload whole application package for adding just even a single template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is another role called Hosted Web Core Web Role, which provide the ability to create virtual directories on VHD.
We will put templates on a folder on VHDs and create virtual directory to them.

According to recent post by the author of Hosted Web Core Web Role, SDK 1.3 provide full support for IIS7, and virtual directory can be created using just Web Role... just wondering how...

Answer (score 2):

I would store them in blob storage.

Comment: As these are aspx pages, how would we make them executable by storing in blob?

Answer (score 0):

There's a technique that was used by the Microsoft research team called a generic worker. In a nutshell, this approach required that the core application was stored elsewhere (like blob storage), then would be pulled down at run time for execution. In theory, this same approach could be used for creating a package that your web app could pull down and load as updates are applied. Thus preventing you from having to redeploy each time an update occurs.

The challenge I see here is the same one that causes issues creating reusable aspx files across web sites. At least last I tried that (several years/versions ago), it wasn't doable. So you may have that same challenge this go-round.